# If you replace functions frequently, does Julia garbage-collect old code?

Tags: julia

In a typical application, the code doesn't get replaced too much, so whether old code gets deallocated before the process exits is inconsequential. However, the use case I'm thinking of is not typical. If I were to replace functions a lot, will Julia garbage-collect old code (source, compiled, and all intermediate representations)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, generated code is never freed.

See for example the discussion in https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/14495.

Comment: *"added this to the 0.5.0 milestone on Dec 28, 2015"*

Comment: _"removed this from the 0.5.0 milestone on Dec 29, 2015"_

Comment: @MattB. or anyone who might know: Is this is a limitation of the LLVM framework itself or just the way Julia uses it?

Comment: I'm not sure what restrictions exist on the LLVM side, but note that old methods (that you replaced) might still be getting called by other tasks or threads whose world age is locked.  I'd imagine simply determining that a particular method _can_ be GC'ed would be a very computationally expensive task.